# How do I know when download from a URL is completed?

Tags: javascript

On my project I use something like the following function to redirect users in order to download a file

```
function promptDownload(file){
      location.href = "http://example.com/downloads/"+file;
}
```

As we all know, when I call this function, browser only prompts a download dialog and does not interrupt my application flow. What I would like to do is to determine when this download completed or cancelled.

There should be something like `onLoad`, `onFinishedLoading`, `onConnectionEnd` or etc but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe you can. If you want _that_ much control, you may need to hand it off to a silverlight/flash app and embed callbacks. (That's like redirecting the user to google.com and knowing when google has finished loading). -- EDIT: You may also be able to use a server-side file handler and ajax client-side to keep both sync'd, but that seems very tedious.

Comment: @Brad: That's what [WeTransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/) does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't determine download progress if you download the file that way.

If you download the file using `XMLHttpRequest`, then you can listen for load, error and progress events like this:

```js
function log(message) {
  return function () {
    alert(message);
  };
}

function download(file, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.responseType = 'blob';
  request.open('GET', file);
  request.addEventListener('load', log('load ' + file));
  request.addEventListener('error', log('error ' + file));
  request.addEventListener('progress', log('progress ' + file));
  request.addEventListener('load', function () {
    callback(request.response);
  });
  request.send();
}

function save(object, mime, name) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(object);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = name;
  a.click();
}

document.querySelector('#download').addEventListener('click', function () {
  download('test.pdf', function (file) {
    save(file, 'application/pdf', 'test.pdf');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="download">Download</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that this only works in browsers which support a.download (not IE)

Comment: IE can support returning blobs: window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob